# Finding neighbours for a an element of an array and making sure it has <4 of them

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, simulation, kdtree

I have an array of atomic coordinates ( a diamond lattice)
That looks like this:

```
                      [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                      [0.0, 0.5, 0.5],
                      [0.5, 0.0, 0.5],
                      [0.5, 0.5, 0.0],
                      [0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
                      [0.25, 0.75, 0.75],
                      [0.75, 0.25, 0.75],
                      [0.75, 0.75, 0.25]]
```

Every atom has an id.
I need to create a bond list, which is essential a neighbour list of atoms that a given atom is connected to.
All interior atoms have to have 4 neighbours (bonds). All surface atoms **can't** have more than 4 neighbours(bonds).

I know how to do it for the interior atoms:
Using kdTree which is fast and works well.

```
kdtree = scipy.spatial.KDTree(Atom_xyz[:,])
Neighs = kdtree.query_pairs(RCUT=1.0)
Neighs = list(Neighs)
```

However it doesn't work for the surface atoms since it doesn't work with periodic images and I need to make sure I have no more than 4 neighbours.
I was wondering if you guys can help me with an algorithm for that.

Here I attach an image of my lattice, where the atoms are visualized as cyan and the bonds are the curvy white.

Diamond lattice where only the interior atoms are bonded:

[image: Diamond lattice where only the interior atoms are bonded]

Answer (score 0):

I just took some four neighbors:

**Note:** the interior atoms may have pathological cases where there are no four neighbors by the Voronoi diagram)

(I used http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_chemistry.html)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial as ssp
from mayavi import mlab
atoms = np.array(
    [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.5, 0.5],
    [0.5, 0.0, 0.5],
    [0.5, 0.5, 0.0],
    [0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
    [0.25, 0.75, 0.75],
    [0.75, 0.25, 0.75],
    [0.75, 0.75, 0.25]])
vor = ssp.Voronoi(atoms)

mlab.figure(1, bgcolor=(0, 0, 0), size=(350, 350))
mlab.clf()

# The position of the atoms
atoms_ridge_x = atoms[vor.ridge_points, 0]
atoms_ridge_y = atoms[vor.ridge_points, 1]
atoms_ridge_z = atoms[vor.ridge_points, 2]
tot_uniq = set()
atoms_count = np.zeros(atoms.shape[0], dtype=int)
for i in range(atoms.shape[0]):
    uniq = [j for j, x in enumerate(vor.ridge_points) if i in x]
    uniq = [x for x in uniq if x not in tot_uniq]
    tot_uniq.update(uniq)
    for k in uniq:
        if atoms_count[i] >= 4:
            continue
        mlab.plot3d(atoms_ridge_x[k, :], atoms_ridge_y[k, :], atoms_ridge_z[k, :],
                    tube_radius=0.05, colormap='Reds')
        atoms_count[vor.ridge_points[k]] += 1

H2 = mlab.points3d(atoms[:, 0], atoms[:, 1], atoms[:, 2],
                   scale_factor=0.2,
                   resolution=20,
                   color=(1, 0, 0),
                   scale_mode='none')

mlab.show()
```